# changing next button on qualtrics

Tags: qualtrics

I have two pages with answers on qualtrics and I need to select the first page, then press the "next" button and see the second page. The first page has the "next" button, the second page does not.
What I succeed for now was only to not display the next button:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  function hideEl(element) {
    if($(element)) $(element).hide();
  }   
  hideEl.defer('NextButton');
});
```

Comment: it looks like `addOnload` function is called on all pages, not only the second one. Could you give more details on where this code is used and what is that you expect to happen?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer!! 
the code is used in qualtrics. Which is a quastionnaires and surveys website where researches can build surveys. 
there is a question and then the participants need to answer yes/no question and to press on the "next button" in order to move to the next page. 
I want to use javascript in order to change the next button and that the participant will answer the yes/no question and automatically move to the next page, without having to press on the nexy button..

Answer (score 0):

Use `click()` to press the Next button. Use addOnReady instead of AddOnload to avoid timing issues.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() {
   //select something here
   $('NextButton').click();
});
```

Your question is not clear about what you are selecting on the first page. The code above will click the Next button immediately after the page loads.  You would need to add code to select whatever it is you are selecting first.

Comment: Thank you!!!

I want that if i press enter then the nextbutton is clicked.
How should I change the code?
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() {
   if e.keyCode=13
   $('NextButton').click();
});